# get "event" from ajax success

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if there's a way to get "event" from ajax success? For example:

UPDATE:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/home/PersonInfo",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
        // I would like to use "data" like data.name, is this possible?    
        }
    });
```

to

```
function MyEvents(start, end, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/home/GetInfo",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data[0].start);
            var events = [];

            var meeting = new Date((data[0].start).getFullYear(),
                         (data[0].start).getMonth(),
                         (data[0].start).getDate());

            while (meeting <= data[0].end) {
                events.push({
                    id: data[0].id,
                    title: data[0].title,
                    start: new Date(meeting.valueOf()),
                    allDay: false
                });
                // increase by one week
                meeting.setDate(meeting.getDate() + 7);
            }
            callback(events);
        }
    });
}
```

data[0].start).getFullYear() is not a function? 
this is the json returned: [{"start":1277985600,"end":1278158400}]
Can anyone help?

Comment: yes, that's possible depending on the data being returned..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have should work, assuming `/home/PersonInfo` gives you valid JSON like this:

```
{"name":"My Persons Name"}
```

Then `data.name` will be `"My Persons Name"` in your callback.

As a side note, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) / Chrome's Developer Tools should allow you to look at the actual request and see the returned JSON as an object.  Plus they give you handy utilities for debugging like `console.dir(data)` to print out the data.

Comment: I've tried it before and data.name is undefined. But I was reading up on "getJSON" and tried data[0].name gave me the right data. I wonder why?

Comment: Look at your JSON being returned, It's probably `[{"name":"My Persons Name"}]`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to use JQueri.getJSON() method, you can find documentation on [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON).

Answer (score 0):

"/home/PersonInfo" needs to return a JSON object. What is your server side code written in?

Comment: MVC or WebForms? If you are using MVC, look up JsonResult.